# 'invalid key error' recaptcha, is my views.py wrong?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, recaptcha

Below I have a signup form. I get no errors in python shell, I have tried to do this with the def signup(request) part but I get 'request' not defined. **My keys are correct, I have checked**. This makes sense to me, but **I am confused as to how to pass this 'request' on correctly in views.py**

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'

    def signup(request):
        recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        data = {
            'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }

        r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data = data)
        result = r.json()

        if result['success']:
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Success')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `session()` and `json.loads()`:

```
class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'

    def signup(request):
        recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        data = {
            'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }

        s = requests.session()

        r = s.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', 
                           data = data)
        result = json.loads(r.text)

        if result['success']:
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Success')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
```